# Ionic login with facebook error: URL must be absolute

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm writing a web app for mobile with `Ionic` framework. I'm trying to add a facebook login option. It is running on my localhost but on my nexus phone it shows me a blank page with this error:

`The redirect_uri URL must be absolute`

LoginCtrl.js:

```
$scope.fbLogin = function () {
            openFB.login(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    } else {
                    }
                }, {
                    scope: 'email,publish_actions'
                });
        }
```

I have configured the `openFB` with my facebook APP_ID. In the facebook `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` I have attached my localhost `oauthcallback.html` file and https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html for `Cordova`.

I have followed [this](https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html) tutorial. Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong and why it doesn't work on my mobile?